# Blazor Server set multiple default values for select drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server app (.net 6) page that has a select drop down list, which is set to allow multiple selected items.  I need to set default values, when the page loads. If I only want to set one selected value, this code works fine.  But, if I want to set multiple values, it does not work.  How can I set the select list default values, when there is more than one value I want to set?  Here is what I have:

```
<select value ="@SelectedCities" @onchange="@((ev) => ListChangeEvent(ev, row_id ))" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" multiple rows="4"> 
     @foreach (var i in item.values.ToList())
     {
       <option id="@i.Key">@i.Value</option> 
     }
</select>


public string[] SelectedCities { get; set; } = new[] { "New York", "Pittsburgh" };
```

The above code does not work.  There are no errors, it simply does not select the two items.

But, if SelectedCities was not an array, like this:

```
public string SelectedCities { get; set; } = "New York";
```

It works fine.

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```html
<select multiple @onchange=HandleChange>
    @foreach(var option in Options)
    {
        <option @key=@option selected=@(chosen.Contains(option)) value=@option>@option</option>
    }
</select>

<pre>@string.Join(", ",chosen)</pre>
```

```cs
@code
{
    string[] Options = new string[] {"Abc","Def","Ghi"};
    string[] chosen = new string[] {"Abc","Ghi"};
    void HandleChange(ChangeEventArgs args)
    => chosen = args.Value as string[];
}
```

[Demo](https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/QQOTFoYX16rZL1uM26)

Comment: Thank you!  I had been struggling with this!

Answer (score 0):

In Blazor 6 (or higher), you no longer need to manually do this. You can bind your collection directly (though you still need to convert it to an array).

Enum example:

```
<select @bind="MyArray" multiple>
    @foreach (var item in (MyEnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)))
    {
        <option value="@item" @key="item">@item.Humanize()</option>
    }
</select>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#multiple-option-selection-with-select-elements